# Repeating loop in C++

Tags: c++, loops

Below is the code for a simple menu in C++. For some reason, if you give it garbage input it will react properly ("Please try your selection again"). However it will then go through the loop one more time giving the error message again, and then finally go back to functioning like normal.

EDIT

The input variable is a char. If the garbage input is only one character long, then the loop works as it is supposed to. If there are any additional characters that will result in the loop being executed more than once before the user is allowed to input anything again.

```
char input = 0;
    while (input != 4)
{
    cout << "1. Circle";
    cout << "\n2. Rectangle";
    cout << "\n3. Triangle";
    cout << "\n4. Quit";
    cout << "\nChoose a shape: ";
    cin >> input;

    switch(input)
    {
    case '1':
        circleFunctions();
        break;
    case '2':
        rectangleFunctions();
        break;
    case '3':           
        triangleFunctions();
        break;
    case '4':
        exit(4);
    default:
        cout << "\nPlease try your selection again...\n";
        input = NULL;
        cin.ignore();
        break;
    }

    cin.ignore();
    cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: See this FAQ: [Why does my program go into an infinite loop when someone enters an invalid input character?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/stream-input-failure.html) -- you're using `ignore` wrong and not calling `clear`.

Comment: I would assume input is an int. What exactly are your asking?

Comment: As answered by Xero, std::cin.clear() should fix it, but be mindful about your input type, it looks like you are comparing it as a number in the while statement, but in the case statements it is a char.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. Adding the following parameters to cin.ignore made it work:

```
    cin.ignore(20, '\n');
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to clear the input buffer when the default case is encountered,

```
std::cin.clear();
```

After that ignore everything in the input stream,

```
std::cin.ignore(INT_MAX);
```

That should put the cin buffer in a good state and the extraction operator (>>) should work properly.

Comment: Interesting.. if the garbage input is only one character long the program functions fine. if there are any additional characters that makes the program loop twice.

Comment: change your cin.ignore() to cin.ignore(INT_MAX); I am not on linux so can't test, but you should be able to fix your problems along these lines.

Comment: That winds up breaking the program for some reason. You will get the error message "Please try your code again" and then nothing.

Comment: The result is the same if you put in normal input as well. It will not display the menu a second time, nor accept any input.